# How to implement a pop-up window to show the row details in APEX interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

I just started to learn about APEX recently. In this [example](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=1855:13:701219327083599::NO:::), if user click one name in the interactive grid, a detail page will pop up. I have searched around the implementation of this function, but I can only find something about the [Enabling Detail View in an Interactive Grid](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/editing-interactive-grid-attributes.htm#GUID-41591922-65DA-4EB7-A0A0-B2F34552DDDF), which is not the thing that I want. Can anybody tell me how to implement such a pop-up detail window(page) in APEX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get such a popup you need 2 steps.

1. create the  detail site where you can link to and which is the edit page.
   In the demo project this is

   - a site with Page Mode Modal Dialog
   - uses Process Fetch Row from Table
   - Form to change the data
2. link out of the interactive grid. 
   Select the Column which should link and then Link -> Target -> Page of Step 1. And select the columns with the ID to match.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Since the table can contain many rows, e.g. 1000 rows. Does that mean I need to create a detail page for each of them manually? Or APEX provides a certain tool to generate the detail page automatically?

Comment: You only need 1 detail page per column you want to use to reference.

Comment: Thanks! I know what you mean. One more question, I have successfully link the column to the modal dialog, while in the pop-up window, all items are blank. How can I retrieve the content from the table based on the `ID/name` we clicked in the interactive grid? Like in sql `select * from table where id = id_in_grid`. How can I pass that parameter to the sql query in modal dialog?

Comment: If you have a link like javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=102:.......:P23_ID:7 Then you need in the edit page a processing Process which selects the row.